# Numpy:Getting rows of array where the corresponding array has a specific value results in IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to find in stackoverflow a thread answering this question, but I could not find. Thus, if it is duplicate, please provide the link.
The use case is very common:
I have two arrays: `X` which contains two dimensional datapoints and `y` which contains labels either 0 or 1.
`X` has shape (307, 2)
`y` has shape (307, 1)
I want to have all rows in `X` where the corresponding row in `y` has value of 1.
I tried the following code:
`X[y==1]`
But it raises the following error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You could try `X[y, :]`

Comment: @MadPhysicist This gives a totally different array -> shape = (307, 1, 2). This is not what I am looking for. Just the rows where the corresponding rows in `y` have a value of 1 -> shape = (9, 2)

Comment: @MadPhysicist And `y` is not an array of boolean values as described in the question. Thus to mask, you have to write a condition which then results in the `IndexError` I also mentioned in the question and have found the reason which is stated in the answer to this question

Comment: `X[y.ravel().astype(np.bool), :]`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following way:

```
X[np.where(np.any(y==1, axis=1))]
```

I also found out that the reason for the above error is that `y` has two dimensions. The following code will work, too, and uses masking which has a better performance:

```
y = y.reshape(-1)
X[y==1,:]
```

Comment: `np.any(y==1, axis=1)` is equivalent to `y.ravel()`. The call to `where` makes this fancy indexing, which is much less efficient than just using the mask.